# what does each dot represent on the reputation chart?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, graphs

I was just wondering (out of interest) what each dot represents on the reputation chart?

Is it activity on a question on a particular day/week?

If it is a question would it be possible to somehow tag each dot with the question it relates to?

Probably a bit of a pipe dream, as I cannot think of a simple solution for this.

So wouldn't want anyone else to waste a lot of time putting a label on the graph points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot represents a day when you earned reputation.

This can be anything from 2 points for an edit or accepting an answer to 200+ points from up-votes, acceptances and bounties on multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

The dots seem to represent particular reputation gains for a span of time, I'm guessing a day. Selecting one dot by dragging the mouse across when I have had significant rep gains in the same day shows me more than one rep gain for one point on the graph.

If you want to see what your recent reputation gains were for, you can click on the envelope next to your name - this gives a better breakdown.